# How do I get the clients in a room of a dynamic nsp?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is the error that I get: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No adapter for this namespace, are you trying to get the list of clients of a dynamic namespace?

My nsp is dynamic, is it not possible to get the clients then? Is there a way to set an adapter for this namespace?

```
// When a student joins, emit the number of students in the classroom 
nsp.in('students').clients((error, clients) => {
    console.log(error);
    nsp.to('instructors').emit(clients.length);
});
```

Each classroom has a dynamic nsp like this courses/:courseId/classroom and I have two rooms students and instructors.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter of the dynamic namespace can be accessed with io.of(socket.nsp.name).adapter.

```
 io.of(socket.nsp.name).adapter.clients((_, clients) => {
    chat.emit("connectionChange", { usersOnline: clients });
 });
```